# Problems getting cocoapods to work in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ruby

I try:

```
pod -v
```

This is my response i get back

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I installed cocoapods with `sudo`, like it says on the website so I dont know what’s wrong.

Comment: What response are you trying to get?

Comment: well i want to do any pod command and i always get that response. even with `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by running

```
brew install ruby
```